# How does DFA minimization work?

Tags: regular-language, automata, dfa, nfa

Is there something wrong with these notes my professor wrote?

[image]

How D&F and B&C are equivalent?

They shouldn't be because transaction functions give different states. If that's okay, and we care about equivalence of the same input accepted or rejected in both states, then why D and B are not equivalent?

---

Additional questions:

What is the difference between transaction and transaction star, if you are familiar with the notation?

What is the difference between sum notation and sum star?

The remark in the bottom says: "...by string epsilon". What does that mean? I didn't get the use of epsilon.

---

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The notes look correct, and I do not know how to answer your question without just repeating essentially what the notes already say.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by "transaction" or "transaction star", but after looking at "sum notation" and "sum star", I suspect that you mean one of the Greek letters.

So first let's deal with that bit of confusion.

This symbol here is not called "sum": Σ

It is a *letter* in the Greek alphabet, called "sigma". Like the Latin alphabet, [Greek letters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_alphabet) have both uppercase and lowercase forms. That symbol is a capital sigma.

That symbol is very frequently used to mean "sum". However, there are certain branches of mathematics where it is traditional to use capital sigma to mean something else. Basically, treat it as just another letter, albeit one that is a little bit weird looking.

Now, because you're studying language theory, there are some traditional things that various letters stand for. This is probably in your text or elsewhere earlier in your prof's notes, but really this is no more mysterious than the convention that "x" often represents how far left or right to put a point, and "y" often represents how far up or down to put a point.

Specifically, in computer science language theory it is traditional to use Σ to mean "alphabet" (as in, something that is a set of characters).

Also, in language theory, if you have a set of anything it is traditional to use that set followed by a superscripted asterisk to mean "strings made up of things in that set". So for example, if I say:

> Let *S* = {0, 1}. Write five examples of elements of *S<sup>*</sup>*

then one adequate answer would be:

> `ϵ   "1"  "111000"  "0101" "110011001100111"`

Note that I used ϵ in there! In language theory, ϵ is used to mean the empty string.

From context, it looks like the notation in your class is to use lowercase delta (δ) to mean the transition function of a DFA. For example, in the first slide, δ(B,0) = D and δ(B,1) = E. Also, it looks like they're using (δ) to mean the function that takes an initial state and a string and tells where that string takes things to. So in the first diagram, δ(A, "11") = E.

Now let's back up and explain every bit of those notes.

First off, in the first slide, the slide starts by saying that two states are equivalent if and only if they accept exactly the same strings starting from those states. Now, lets look at what strings are accepted starting from B and from C: any string starting with "1" goes to E and is accepted (since after E, all paths lead back to E again); any string starting with "0" goes to either D or F, where it stays, and is rejected.

You ask why B and D are not equivalent - consider the string "1", with just a single character. If you start from B, that string is accepted. (Because it goes to E, an accepting state) If you start from D, that string is rejected (because D, where it ends up, is not an accepting state).

Now the definition at the top of the second stage is just putting this notion of whether strings have different outcomes starting from different states into formal language. It says that two states are equivalent if whether they end up in an accepting state after following some string *w* is the same for both states, for all strings *w*. Otherwise, there's some string *w* such that from one state you reach an accepting state when continuing on with *w*, and from the other state you end up in a non-accepting state. Then you say that the states are "distinguishable" by that string *w*.

The remark at the bottom that you asked about is simply noting that an accepting state and a non-accepting state are always distinguishable by the empty string (remember, in language theory that's what ϵ means). This makes sense, since δ<sup>*</sup>(A,ϵ) = A for all states A and all DFAs (following the empty string never goes anywhere).